# buffer-local function in elisp

Tags: function, emacs, elisp, buffer, local

I would like to redefine an existing function `foo`, but for a specific buffer only.

```
(defun foo ()
  (message "Not done:("))
```

I was hopping this will do:

```
(make-local-variable 'foo)
(fset 'foo #'(lambda () (message "Done!")))
```

But it does not.
Any ideas?

[EDIT:
Alternatively, because the function is bounded to a key, it would suffice to modify the binding just for the current buffer. But I don't see how to do it. Local keymap is shared by the all buffers in the major mode. Modifying it modifies the bindings in all the buffers with this major mode.

The only ugly solution which I am able to think of, is is to set a keymap text-property for the whole buffer. Is this the only way to proceed?]

Comment: What is the problem you're actually trying to solve?  Perhaps there's a different approach that would work better.  How do you know when you want "Done!" and "Not done:("?

Comment: @Trey The package's help-mode has a navigation function (jumping to sections). It is short and elegant. But for one very specific type of help file I need different behavior. Instead of building the feature into the function I was hoping to be able to redefine it locally. Your answer does what I want in fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about writing your symbol-functions to symbol-values, then evaluate them by some other function?

```
(defvar my-buffer-local-function
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (message "Default message"))
  "This variable contains buffer local function")

(make-variable-buffer-local 'my-buffer-local-function)

(defun run-my-buffer-local-function (&rest args)
  "This function run buffer-local function"
  (interactive)
  (if (called-interactively-p 'any)   ;To call interactively AND to
                                      ;be able to have elisp-calls
    (call-interactively my-buffer-local-function)
    (apply my-buffer-local-function args)))

(setq my-buffer-local-function
  (lambda (&optional arg)
    (interactive "sinsert message: ")
    (message (concat "Not so default message: " arg))))
```

The visible bad side, is that it works well if `my-buffer-local-function` is interactive. If not, `run-my-buffer-local-function` will still be interactive, and visible in `M-x` list. I think you cannot make sometimes-interactive functions, because `interactive` should be top-level call.

Btw, you can name function and value with the same name.

Comment: Cool trick. It addresses the best my question so far. Though it's a bit lengthy for my purpose. I will keep this in my mind for the future.

Answer (score 6):

You can make a function which does the overriding for you, something along the lines of this:

```
(defun override-the-keymap ()
  (let ((my-overriding-keymap (make-sparse-keymap)))
(set-keymap-parent my-overriding-keymap (current-local-map))
(use-local-map my-overriding-keymap)
(define-key my-overriding-keymap (kbd "C-M-x") 
      '(lambda () (interactive) (message "Done!")))))
```

Obviously customize the key binding appropriately.  This has the effect only in the current buffer.

Comment: This does the trick and I will go for it, but @desudesudesu answer address the original question of making functions buffer-local which has a bit of a theoretical side to it. Thus I am accepting his answer.

Answer (score 5):

The value and function properties of a given symbol are separate, and so presumably `make-local-variable` will only affect the *value*, whereas `fset` operates on the *function* property.

You are probably better off describing in more detail what it is that you want to do, but one generic solution would be to use "around advice" to wrap the original function with your own code.

```
(defadvice foo (around my-foo-wrapper)
  (if (not (and (boundp 'use-my-foo) 'use-my-foo))
      ad-do-it
    (message "Not done:(")))
(ad-activate 'foo)

;; in special buffer
(set (make-local-variable 'use-my-foo) t)
```

**EDIT:** (regarding the additional key-map comments)

Perhaps then you want to define a minor-mode for use in your special buffer. Minor mode key-maps take precedence over those of the major mode, so you would simply need to define that same binding in the minor mode's map. See `define-minor-mode`.

Comment: This is for my package, so I can modify the function directly instead of advising it. The problem is that for one *very* specific buffer I need a different functionality and don't want to kludge the function just for this very particular case. This is an interactive function so modifying the map locally would do. But I don't know how to do it either. Edited the Q.

Answer (score 2):

If the function definition is to be buffer-specific that is usually a sign that it is to be major mode-specific.  If that is in fact the case here, then the right way to deal with it is to use a different function adapted to that specific buffer/mode.  If the problem is a key binding, then just bind the key to the specialized function in the major mode's keymap.